# What properties should a number $n$ have so there is an integer $k$ where $n = k \cdot (k+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

This is my first question here so please bear with me:)

What properties should a natural number $n$ have so there is an integer $k$ where $n = k \cdot (k+1)$? By properties, I mean things such as divisibility, prime factors, etc. I tried using quadratic equations but couldn't come up with anything.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  For one thing, $n=k(k+1)$ must be even

Comment: Since $k, k+1$ are subsequent integers, one of them is even. Hence $n$ is necessarily even.

Comment: $2k+1=\pm\sqrt{4n+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer $n$ has this property iff
$$n=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor(\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor +1) $$

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the right answer:

If $n = k \cdot (k+1)$, then $-k^2 - k + n = 0$ and using the quadratic equation, we have $k = \frac {1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4n}}{-2}$ so $1 + 4n$ needs to be a perfect square.

Comment: The quadratic equation has two solutions.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry.I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can view it as a quadratic equation, which can be solved
$$n=k(k+1)\\k^2+k-n=0\\
k=\frac 12\left(-1\pm\sqrt{1+4n} \right)$$
So you need $1+4n$ to be a square.  The square root will be odd, so the division by $2$ is no problem.  The two signs give one solution with $k \gt 0$ and the other with $k \lt 0$, negating both $k,k+1$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The reason I accepted another answer is because this was a sub-problem in a harder problem I was trying to do and your answer would be like a recursive answer although you're answer is more straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Well, the condition that it is equal to some $k(k+1)$ *IS* a condition that will make this true.

You can list these numbers by letting $k$ be any integer and letting $n = k(k+1)$

You can determine if an arbitrary number $n$ has this condition by finding $k$ so that $k^2 \le n < (k+1)^2$ (there will always be a unique such integer for all natural $n$; we could write this as $k=\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$) and checking whether $n-k^2 = k$ or not.

If $n - (\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor)^2 = \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ then $n$ has the condition and if not then $n$ doesn't.

But that's not really an *answer* as that's just another way of saying $n = k^2 +k = k(k+1)$.  i.e. it is true when it is true.  But it does tell you how to check if it is true.